# calling c functions from python

Tags: python, c

I have some code written in c that i want to call from python. Is there a way to do this. I looked at several documentations but they look quite vague. Can some one give me some specific steps please

Edit:

I wrote below dll called djj.dll
it has a file called try.cpp with following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int print(){

return 4;

}
```

Now, i build this dll and go to python idle.

I type print windll.djj.print  . It gives syntax error .WHY??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python

Comment: The easiest way is with ctypes. The ctypes tutorial is excellent.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  `print` is a reserved word in Python 2.X (Python 3 changes it to an ordinary predefined function).  What happens if you change the name of your C function from `print` to, say, `Print`?